# How to use an svg to cut *many* holes into a flat plane?

Tags: svg, boolean-modifier

I am currently trying to 3D model a trophy for a film festival. Roughly speaking, the trophy will look like two people holding a large strip of film. For this model, i need to extrude the following 2D Shape:

[image]

I have created this shape as an SVG using InkScape. It is proving quite difficult for me to import it into blender and extrude it however. The SVG is *one* path, and blender succesfully imports it as one curve. I convert this curve to a mesh, enter edit mode, and everything looks just fine:

[image]

Here is the problem: How do i create one face from this that I can extrude? There's no easy way I can see to select the nodes in a way where I make just this face. An alternative approach would be to make one SVG object be the outer edge and another SVG object be the holes. Then I could easily select every node on the outer edge and make a face, extrude it, then (somewhat) easily make a face for every hole, extrude all those faces, and use a boolean modifier to remove that from the outer edge. This works in theory, but the object I get from applying the boolean modifier is an absolute mess with non-manifold edges everywhere. Also yes, I have checked that my normals are correct.

What's the best way to accomplish this thing I am trying to do?

Any help is appreciated.

The SVG in question is here (not allowed to embed the svg file itself):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="172.53326mm"
   height="13.507841mm"
   viewBox="0 0 172.53326 13.507841"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2338"
   inkscape:version="1.0.2-2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15)"
   sodipodi:docname="SvgTest3.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2332" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="293.91946"
     inkscape:cy="149.65288"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1009"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata2335">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-7.0933692,-25.184845)">
    <path
       id="rect886"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#f10000;stroke-width:0.412001;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:0.979839"
       d="m 7.2993697,25.390846 v 13.09584 H 179.42064 v 
        -13.09584 h -18.973 a 6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 
        -1.66966,2.875277 6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 -8.7881,0 
        6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 -1.66966,-2.875277 H 
        33.440409 a 6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 
        -1.624706,2.695959 6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 
        -8.787578,0 6.2140163,5.8849331 0 0 1 
        -1.62419,-2.695959 z m 4.3733763,5.303552 c 1.473151,0 
        2.659269,1.02026 2.659269,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186118,2.287198 -2.659269,2.287198 
        -1.47314,0 -2.659269,-1.020238 -2.659269,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.186129,-2.287198 
        2.659269,-2.287198 z m 10.422103,0 c 1.47314,0 
        2.659269,1.02026 2.659269,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186129,2.287198 -2.659269,2.287198 
        -1.47315,0 -2.658753,-1.020238 -2.658753,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185603,-2.287198 
        2.658753,-2.287198 z m 10.583332,0 c 1.473152,0 
        2.659271,1.02026 2.659271,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186129,2.287198 -2.659271,2.287198 
        -1.473139,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185611,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.583333,0 c 1.473153,0 
        2.659272,1.02026 2.659272,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186119,2.287198 -2.659272,2.287198 
        -1.473139,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185611,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.583333,0 c 1.473142,0 
        2.659272,1.02026 2.659272,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 -2.659272,2.287198 
        -1.473149,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185601,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.583334,0 c 1.473141,0 
        2.659271,1.02026 2.659271,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 -2.659271,2.287198 
        -1.47314,0 -2.658751,-1.020238 -2.658751,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185611,-2.287198 
        2.658751,-2.287198 z m 10.583333,0 c 1.473147,0 
        2.659271,1.02026 2.659271,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186124,2.287198 -2.659271,2.287198 
        -1.473142,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185608,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.583333,0 c 1.473147,0 
        2.659271,1.02026 2.659271,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186124,2.287198 -2.659271,2.287198 
        -1.473139,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185611,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.583333,0 c 1.473145,0 
        2.659272,1.02026 2.659272,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.186127,2.287198 -2.659272,2.287198 
        -1.473142,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.185608,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.58333,0 c 1.47315,0 
        2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 0,1.26696 
        -1.18612,2.287198 -2.65927,2.287198 -1.47315,0 
        -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v -1.99471 c 
        0,-1.266938 1.1856,-2.287198 2.65875,-2.287198 z m 
        10.58334,0 c 1.47314,0 2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 
        v 1.99471 c 0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 
        -2.65927,2.287198 -1.47315,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 
        -2.65875,-2.287198 v -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 
        1.1856,-2.287198 2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.58333,0 c 
        1.47314,0 2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 -2.65927,2.287198 
        -1.47314,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.18561,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.58333,0 c 1.47314,0 
        2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 0,1.26696 
        -1.18613,2.287198 -2.65927,2.287198 -1.47314,0 
        -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v -1.99471 c 
        0,-1.266938 1.18561,-2.287198 2.65875,-2.287198 z m 
        10.58334,0 c 1.47314,0 2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 
        v 1.99471 c 0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 
        -2.65927,2.287198 -1.47315,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 
        -2.65875,-2.287198 v -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 
        1.1856,-2.287198 2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.58333,0 c 
        1.47314,0 2.65926,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 
        0,1.26696 -1.18613,2.287198 -2.65927,2.287198 
        -1.47315,0 -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v 
        -1.99471 c 0,-1.266938 1.1856,-2.287198 
        2.65875,-2.287198 z m 10.58333,0 c 1.47314,0 
        2.65927,1.02026 2.65927,2.287198 v 1.99471 c 0,1.26696 
        -1.18613,2.287198 -2.65927,2.287198 -1.47314,0 
        -2.65875,-1.020238 -2.65875,-2.287198 v -1.99471 c 
        0,-1.266938 1.18561,-2.287198 2.65875,-2.287198 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Convert to mesh then Alt F?

Comment: [Model it](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qoErpAKl/), instead? (Increase Subdiv. level to 1.. I left it off by accident)

Comment: if you don't need to bend the strip and it's only straight with an extrude thickness then Cornivius answer will suffice.

Answer (score 5):

If you import the SVG into blender it'd be a path/Curve. If you go to the curve tab on the right hand menus and set it to 2D, and Fill Mode 'Both' it should give you a flat object where the inside lines create the holes.

[image]

You can also Extrude it in the Geometry section on the right. Then you can just convert it to a mesh. If it's going to be deformed then probably give it a Sharp remesh modifier too

Import SVG is an addon that comes with Blender. In case you don't have it activates, got to Edit->Preferences->Add ons and search SVG, then activate it
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but the generated mesh is unfortunately filled with nonmanifold edges everywhere. Will I maybe just have to model this, like @Robin Betts sugests?

Comment: Does a Remesh modifier in sharp mode not solve that issue? If the curve is very messy when you import it, in Edit mode, go to Curve->Clean Up->Decimate curve. This might solve it. Otherwise, yea, modeling it would be quicker

Comment: For modeling you can't have 1 face. each of the holes needs to be connected to the outside vertices with 2 edges. The quicker way to model this would be to separate the wholes into another object, fill them and extrude them so they are solid 'cylinders' and use them with a boolean modifier on the original part, that you have also filled and extruded. That will cut the holes throw it without having to connect them manually

Comment: Hi @Cornivius. I ended up splitting the SVG into smaller parts i could model manually (fill in the faces) and then copy paste and join. Unfortunately, the remesh modifier fails to even apply, and extruding the holes as a seperate object and then using a boolean modifier also generates a ton of non-manifold edges.